# Methods to modify Ambient Display

Tags: custom-roms, screen, system

I am trying to modify Ambient Display as the one in my ROM is missing on some features, such as Pick up and Hand Wave gestures.

I have researched a bit and found that Ambient display feature(s) reside in SystemUI.apk and framework-res.apk and I have successfully pulled them.

Is there any way to integrate/enable the features?

Comment: Pulling the APK files is easy, but writing them back is not that easy. Without root or unlocked bootloader it is impossible.

Comment: I have been able to enable the features, albeit in the xml files only. I have root access and unlocked bootloader. I have successfully recompiled the apk and installed it but the system is crashing now. Any ideas on what could possibly be wrong with the recompiled and signed apk?

Comment: use `adb logcat` to see what is going wrong. It works already while the boot process has not yet finished.